# Delete a key in dictionary but keep the value in place

Tags: python, json, dictionary, parsing

For input json,

```
{
  "dataSet": {
    "integerFields": {
      "patient_display_id": "1",
      "ehmrn": "123",
      "enctrid": "456"
    },
     "DecimalFields": {
      "class": "1",
      "section": "123",
      "enctrid": "456"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to delete ***integerFields*** but keep the value of it, an output something like this. But keep rest of the fields intact

```
{
  "dataSet": {
      "patient_display_id": "1",
      "ehmrn": "123",
      "enctrid": "456",
      "DecimalFields": {
      "class": "1",
      "section": "123",
      "enctrid": "456"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just assign it's value to the key containing it, it will be overwritten

```py
inputDict = {'entity': {'dataSet': {'integerFields': {'patient_display_id': '1'}}}}
inputDict['entity']['dataSet'] = inputDict['entity']['dataSet']['integerFields']
print(inputDict)
```

Comment: thank you but I think I missed a part in the question, I want the rest of the fields to be intact

Comment: @Rakesh I'm not sure what you mean by that, the only thing removed in this process is the key `'integerFields'`, nothing else is lost.

Comment: my bad again, I have updated now

Answer (score 2):

Merge the keys of the `integerFields` dictionary with the `dataSet` dictionary, then delete the `integerFields` key:

```py
import json

input_json = '''\
{
  "dataSet": {
    "integerFields": {
      "patient_display_id": "1",
      "ehmrn": "123",
      "enctrid": "456"
    },
    "DecimalFields": {
      "class": "1",
      "section": "123",
      "enctrid": "456"
    }
  }
}'''
data = json.loads(input_json)
data['dataSet'].update(data['dataSet']['integerFields'])
del data['dataSet']['integerFields']
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Output:

```json
{
  "dataSet": {
    "DecimalFields": {
      "class": "1",
      "section": "123",
      "enctrid": "456"
    },
    "patient_display_id": "1",
    "ehmrn": "123",
    "enctrid": "456"
  }
}
```